In a sentence consisting of three clauses, sometimes it's hard to tell which clause is parallel to which

In conclusion, it is my conviction that prohibiting tourist activities for the sake of local culture is an unwise proposal. This is because it is pointless to try to stop change and because such a ban would upset the equilibrium of the local economy and cause hardship for local people whose living depends on the influx of holidaymakers.

Here's a short version for ease of viewing:

Point. This is because [clause A] and because [clause B].

My last sentence needs to point out both of the following reasons:
 1. it is pointless to stop change
2. such a ban would...
Now, I want to remove the second because to avoid repetition, however, if I did it, it could be difficult for readers to know whether the second point is independent or attached to This is because.
I encounter this kind of situation pretty frequently in writing and wonder what native speakers would do in such a case.

I don't think the second "because"  sounds repetitive. If you used "because" five or more times in the same writing task that would be different but one way to avoid repeating the conjunction (or preposition) would be to write: “Bla bla bla for two reasons. First, bla bla bla. Second, and the most important,  bla bla bla."

“… it is pointless to stop change and such a ban would upset… which would cause hardship ....” This also works for me.

"This is because" is clumsy. Strike it and the next "because". "it is pointless to try and stop change" is a platitude. Strike it.  Leave the rest.

Edit

... prohibiting ... This is because [it is pointless to try to stop change] and ... [such a ban would [upset the equilibrium of the local economy] and [cause hardship for local people whose living depends on the influx of holidaymakers]].

The square brackets are for clarity.
The sentence should be understood without the second because.  The second reason contains ban, which should help readers to link back to the earlier part described by to try to stop and further back described by prohibiting.
The sentence would be less clumsy without This is because and the second because.  Breaking up the sentence into two may help too:

It is pointless to try to stop change. Further, such a ban would upset the equilibrium of the local economy and cause hardship for local people whose living depends on the influx of holidaymakers.


The conjunction "and" is used twice:  "This is because [it is pointless to try to stop change] and ... [such a ban would upset the equilibrium …] and [cause hardship for local people whose living…]. Not my downvote.

Thanks, @Mari-Lou A, for your comments.  These are helpful as they point out problems for answerers to improve their posts.  I knew and is used twice; the second one links the two predicates in the second clause.  I didn’t think that would be a problem and hence didn’t state that.  I’m not sure whether the downvote is due to that and whether having two ands is a problem.
